# composer error : 'does not contain valid JS'

Tags: zend-framework, compiler-errors, installation

I am trying to install zendframework2 via Composer on my command line.

the composer command is (taken from Zendframework page)

```
php composer.phar create-project --repository-url="http://packages.zendframework.com" zendframework/skeleton-application path/to/install
```

I received the following message:

```
[Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException]
  "http://packages.zendframework.com/packages.json" does not contain valid JS
  ON
  Parse error on line 1:
  ▒{    "packages": {
  ^
  Expected one of: 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I can correct this error?

Comment: Did they break something again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with that repository, try this:

```
php composer.phar create-project --repository-url="https://packagist.org/" -s dev zendframework/skeleton-application path/to/install
```

Notice that the --repository-url has been set to https://packagist.org/ and also there is a  -s dev options. Finally be sure to change path/to/install to the right place.

Comment: Hello Jeff. Thank you very much for your kind advice. it worked. warmed regards Andreea